# Wordpress WooCommerce booking different prices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I bought WooCommerce booking plugin for WordPress because my client want to rent trailers. There is a problem for the different prices.

Trailer A has a price of 60 euro a day.
When someone rent it for a weekend it is 100 euro for the weekend.
For a week it will be 200 euro and for a month 500 euro.

The problem is that with date ranges its not working that way:

[image: Range dat WooCommerce]

I booked the same item 2 times for a week. one starting from sunday to saturday and the other from monday to sunday. Both are one week but they have a different price because the weekend range date...
[image: WooCommerce different prices]

Is there a correct way for this? I have the same problem if i book for a month, it takes the other date ranges also.

EDIT:

When i use this date range it works better but still not 100% the good way because i wanna use round values for the client in admin & front-end
[image: WooCommerce price date range]

[image: Cart WooCommerce date ranges]

Answer (score 1):

Set decimals to **0** on `WooCommerce > Settings > General > Number of decimals`.
It will show products that are **€199.50** as **€200** -this will work for the front-end but unfortunately will not work for admin.

Finally, go to `WooCommerce > Status > Tools > WooCommerce transients` and click on **Clear Transients**.